# how to check if both query strings (with wildcards) are present using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have two query strings, both of which contains wildcards. We can check if any of the two query strings are present like below:

```
import re
def wildcards2regex (pattern):
    return ( pattern.replace('?', '[a-zA-Z]{1}').replace('*', '.*') )

string = 'christopher susan'
s1='chris*'
r1 = wildcards2regex(s1)
s2 = 'sus??'
r2 = wildcards2regex(s2)
q = r1+'|'+r2
bool(re.search(q, string))
```

Now I wonder what to do if I want to check if both query string are present?  obviously replacing '|' with '&' does not work.  Do anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

You may consider this code:

```sh
>>> import re
>>> def wildcards2regex (pattern):
...    return ( pattern.replace('?', '[a-zA-Z]').replace('*', '.*') )
...
>>> string = 'christopher susan'
>>> s1='chris*'
>>> r1 = wildcards2regex(s1)
>>> s2 = 'sus??'
>>> r2 = wildcards2regex(s2)
>>> q = re.compile(r'(?=.*{})(?=.*{})'.format(r1, r2))
>>> bool(re.search(q, string))
True
```

Take note of this regex building:

```
q = re.compile(r'(?=.*{})(?=.*{})'.format(r1, r2))
```

Here we are building a regex with 2 conditions defined using [positive lookahead assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that asserts both of your query strings.

Comment: @zesla: Did this not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple independently positioned search terms into one regex using positive lookahead, since that doesn't consume characters or advance the conceptual cursor.

```
^(?=.*term1)(?=.*term2)
```

*Demonstration:* https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E(%3F%3D.*term1)(%3F%3D.*term2)&test_string=Here%20are%20term1%20and%20term2.